# Lifting state up - this.state.friends suddenly undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand why I get this error whenever a "add to inner circle button" gets clicked (in Frienddetail.js). I am using props to lift state up from Frienddetail to Friends:

```
addToInnerCircle [as innerCircle]
C:/Users/charl/Desktop/IRONHACK/Week-9/finalproject/client/src/pages/Friends.js:64
  61 |    }
  62 | 
  63 |    addToInnerCircle(idclicked){
> 64 |        console.log("hallo")
     | ^  65 |        let idpicked = this.state.friends
  66 |        // .filter(friend => friend._id === idclicked)
  67 |        console.log("Charles")
```

let idpicked = this.state.friends => gives undefined but I don't understand why?

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

---

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import './Friends.css'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Frienddetail from '../components/Frienddetail'
import InnerCircleDetail from '../components/InnerCircleDetail'
import { getUser } from '../utils/auth'

class Friendsfollowers extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            friends: [],
            searchFriends: [],
            innerCircle: [],
            searchInnerCircle: []       
        }
        
        this.searchFriends=this.searchFriends.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){ 
        Axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/friends`,
            withCredentials: true       
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response)
            let friendslist = response.data // eslint-disable-next-line
            let friendslistupdate = friendslist.filter(friend => {
                if(friend.username){
                    if(friend.username !== getUser().username){
                        return true
                    }
                }
            })
            this.setState({
                friends: friendslistupdate,
                searchFriends: friendslistupdate
            })
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log("Charles made an error when retrieving all friends: ",error)
        })
    }

    searchFriends(e){ 
        console.log(getUser) 
        let friendsearched = this.state.friends.filter(friend => { 
            if(friend.username){
                if(friend.username.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
                    return true
                }
            }
        })
        this.setState({
            searchFriends:friendsearched
        })
    }

    addToInnerCircle(idclicked){
        console.log("hallo")
        let idpicked = this.state.friends
        // .filter(friend => friend._id === idclicked)
        console.log("Charles")
        console.log(idpicked)
        console.log("Charles")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
            <div className="friendsoverviewcontainer">
                <h1>Our community</h1>
                <form className="friends">               
                    <div className="titlepart">
                        <label className="friendlabel" htmlFor="friend">Search for Users :</label><br></br>
                        <input className="friendform" type="text" name="friend" value={this.state.friend} placeholder="Type a username here!" onChange={this.searchFriends}></input>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div className="friendsboxes" >
                    {
                        this.state.searchFriends.map(friend =>
                            <div key={friend._id}>
                                <Frienddetail 
                                    key={friend._id}
                                    id={friend._id}
                                    username={friend.username}
                                    location={friend.location}
                                    innerCircle={this.addToInnerCircle}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )   
                    }
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div className="innercirclecontainer">
                <h1>Your inner circle</h1>
                <div className="innercircleboxes">
                    {
                        this.state.searchInnerCircle.map(inner =>
                            <div key={inner._id}>
                                <InnerCircleDetail 
                                    key={inner._id}
                                    id={inner._id}
                                    username={inner.username}
                                    location={inner.location}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )   
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Friendsfollowers
```

---

**Frienddetail.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Frienddetail.css'

class Frienddetail extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="friendbox">
                    <img className="imagedaredevilspicdetail" src="/images/profileimage.png" alt="picturesetting" />
                    <p className="friend">{this.props.username}</p>
                    <p className="friend">{this.props.location}</p>
                    <button className="followbutton">Follow user!</button>
                    <button className="friendbutton" onClick={(e)=> this.props.innerCircle(this.props.id)}>Add to inner circle!</button>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Frienddetail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use this inside a callback function you need to bind it or react interprets "this" as a window object and not an instance of a class and window object has no state variable so this.state is undefined. what you have done for your searchFriends function you need to do the same for addToInnerCircle or a better way that I like to use which has no problem of binding is to use arrow function syntax just convert your addToInnerCircle into an arrow function.

Read more on react js docs handling events

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this

```
import React from "react";

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: props.id
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.innerCircle(this.state.id);
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

In your Frienddetail component.

Lemmi know if this works